# What causes a div to align items horizontally even when I set it to display: block?

Tags: html, css

As I understand it, `display: block` is the default setting. But even after manually setting `display: block`, the `div` is still aligning items horizontally. The only way to fix it was to use:

```
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
```

What could be the cause of this?

Comment: It has `float`?

Comment: no. in fact, I have tried to remove all other properties to see if the behavior is fix. It is not.

Comment: 'the div is still aligning items horizontally' - if the div is display: block that won't dictate how its descendants are laid out, but the descendants themselves may have settings which make them horizontally laid out. Please add enough code into your question so we can see the problem, as it stands any answer is just a guess

Comment: I found out the issue. I have some other element that is changing the style of this `div`. I am currently refactoring terrible code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on what is inside the `div`, could be there are tags which have `float: left|right`, `display: inline-block|inline` or you have `span` tags inside the div, `span` tags are `inline` by default, so they will be aligned horizontally.

**EDIT**: There are many more `inline` elements like `span`, so check what elements you have in the `div`, it will tell you the reason to your problem.